# parsing public_custom_profile_fields in discussion forum

Tags: ee2, forum

Expressionengine 2.5.5 and Discussion Forums 3.1.10

How do i pass public_custom_profile_fields in forum_thread.html section of the forum.

i have tried placing  {custom_profile_fields} in forum_thread.html section but nothing gets displayed.

i am trying to display field name  in forum section so that i can create a custom label to a specific member and display it in forum section.

thanks

Comment: Anyone please ? I have been doing some research and i have found the plugin here http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/58197/  what i need to do, but i think its not compatible with EE 2+ as i cant seem to get it to work, its displays under plugins in EE but i cant do anything with it.

Comment: anyone at all, i am trying to add a custom field to a member in a forum.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the Forum template through the normal template parsing engine, it has it caveats but it might get what you looking for.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/forum/other_features.html#running-the-forums-through-regular-templates